# Quickest way to check internet connectivity in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a html file that checks for connectivity, but the problem here is that it takes about 10 seconds to throw the alert message box to indicate the connection is lost. I want to know if there's a much faster way to inform the user that the connection is lost without having to wait.
Strictly JS thanks...

JS code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function SubmitButton()
{
    if(navigator.onLine)
    {
            document.getElementById('SubmitBtn').style.visibility='visible';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('SubmitBtn').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
}
function Online() 
{ 
    var status=false;
    status= navigator.onLine;
    if(status!= true)
    {
        alert('Network connectivity is lost, please try again later');
    }
}
</script>
```

Calling it in html file here:

```
<INPUT name="ccMCA1input" type="checkbox" onclick="ccMCA1.ccEvaluate(),Online()" value=False>
```

Comment: Is this way faster? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249744/851498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.onLine) is the only built-in property which can be checked (and not reliable btw).
You could create a XHR request to a reliable server, and check whether any response is being received.

Comment: AFAIK, window.navigator.onLine will check whether the browser is set to browse the content online. It does not check about the internet connectivity in your PC. It will work only when you set your browser specifically to browse offline.

Answer (score 7):

You could periodically request a 1x1 gif image from a(ny) server, making sure you use the [cache buster method](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/) to avoid caching. You could use the [onload](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/load.html) and [onerror](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html) events.

```
var isOnline = (function isOnline(){
  // Create a closure to enclose some repeating data
  var state = false;
  var src = 'gif_url?t=' + Date.now();
  var function onLoad = function(){state = true;}
  var function onError = function(){state = false;}

  // Inside the closure, we create our monitor
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onLoad;
    img.onerror = onError;
    img.src = src;
  }, 10000);

  // Return a function that when called, returns the state in the closure
  return function(){return state;};
}());

//Use as
var amIOnline = isOnline();
```

Comment: Thanks, seems a neaty way of doing things.

Comment: Hmm but if one calls multiple times the function, we could have a lot of checks, since you're using `setInterval`...

Comment: @franzlorenzon unless you modify this code to just run once, collect "listeners" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking out the following URLs:

1. [Online connectivity monitoring](http://html5demos.com/offline)
2. [navigator.onLine testing](http://html5demos.com/nav-online)
3. [on/offline event capture](http://html5demos.com/offline-events)

Comment: @Joseph And then you did the exact same thing ;)

Comment: @AndreasAL did the exact same thing? "providing an answer" (solutions+methods+references) is not the same as "providing a set of links"

Comment: Went over the post quickly. Sounds a bit ambiguous, but probably the gist is to put more content in the answers. Will keep in mind.

Comment: @Joseph No not your answer witch is good and a save way to check for connection. But your comment to this post. ...